# How can I make an animation effect on the canvas while moving?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, duration

Is it possible to make an animation effect on the canvas while moving?
I just need to make an animation movement between canvas' positions,

Like in css3: `-webkit-transition-duration: 1s`;

Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      #myCanvas {
              -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      }
</style>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;color:red;"></canvas>
    <script>   
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var w = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      timer = setInterval(function() { 

            var f = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*680);
            var f2 = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*400);
          console.log (f, f2);

            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.fillRect(f, f2, 100, 50); 
            w.onclick = function() {
                clearInterval(timer);
                falling();
            } 
         }, 300 //the seconds of interval movement)
        function falling(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
            ctx.fillRect(500,500,100,50)

        }              
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "while moving" what ? if you want the transition positions between your random positions, just calculate these and redraw your objects at their new positions. There are a lot of canvas animation tutorials out-there, you may want to read one.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you just want to calculate interim positions along a line from a starting point to an ending point then you can do it like this:

```
// percentComplete is a number between 0.00 and 1.00
// representing the current progress of the animation from start to end
var x = startingX+(endingX-startingX)*percentComplete;
var y = startingY+(endingY-startingY)*percentComplete;
```

If you want to animate with flair, then you can use Robert Penner's [easing functions](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) to animate in a non-linear way.

To include a fixed duration for your animation you can calculate percentComplete based as:

```
var percentComplete = elapsedTime / animationDuration;
```